# How can I update WSL2 kernel?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to run `wsl --update` in cmd (my current version is 4.19.104), but I can't update to newest version 4.19.121 which is needed for GPU support because it says there is no available update.
Windows build 20170.rs_prerelease, Beta channel

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running exactly?  Please provide the exact build you are on.  Please indicate which Insider Preview (Beta or Developer) channel you are receiving builds for, do not reply with a comment, instead edit your question

Comment: Please provide the output of *wsl.exe --update --status*

Answer (score 2):

It has recently become **simpler to update the WSL 2 Kernel: turn on "Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows OR  Receive updates for other Microsoft products** (Windows 10/Windows 11) in the Advanced options for Windows update. The WSL2 kernel will get updated automatically.

You can also install a slightly higher (minor version) from the Microsoft Catalog manually, but Windows Update (with the setting above) will attempt to downgrade you back to the lower version it thinks you should have. It is not worth the hassle to do manual updates (very little difference in kernel versions), but if you choose to do so DL the kernel from the link below, and make sure you have "Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows" off.

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=wsl

PS: you can also get even more granular with your version choices on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/releases) (I assume you should also have "Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows" off.)

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5650)

Comment: what if your organization has this setting off and disabled as a group policy?

Comment: @user39160 then you must ask your administrator to change the setting or push the update.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, this update is only available with [Windows Insider Preview Build 20150](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2020/06/17/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20150/). Make sure you have that installed and up to date.

On this [Windows Dev Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/gpu-compute-wsl-install-and-wsl-update-arrive-in-the-windows-insiders-fast-ring-for-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/), they describe all the steps required to install the latest builds and WSL updates, check the status of your currently installed version, and rollback to a previous version.

According to that blog post, if you have the necessary requirements to install the update, it will come through Windows Update when you check for updates.

If you are having issues, it might be best to file and update them on the [WSL Repository](https://github.com/microsoft/wsl).